# Node/Javascript: Redirect After Verification Button

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, button, model-view-controller

I'm using a framework called [PartialJS](http://docs.partialjs.com/) that follows a MVC architecture to build a webApp that will verify a user's input and make a request to an API and render the API response.

I'm not sure how to redirect the user to the rendered page after verification and API call has finished. Where should the page redirect and API calls be made?

Here's a quick breakdown of what the user will see with 'bullet' marks denoting what happens in the backend:

1. User presented with a form and fills information

   - exports.onValidation() called via a serialized JSON to verify that
     all fields completed accurately (triggered by a button), done without
     a page refresh.
   - API call is made with user's information, will not return until response is received and parsed
2. Form rendered with decoded JSON response from external API

I have tried using this in the 'view.html' page but the page redirects before verification.

```
<buttononclick="window.location='http://www.CaliCoder.com/results';">Submit</button>        
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('button').bind('click', function() {
            $.post('/', $('#f').serialize(), function(d) {
                var err = $('#error');

                if (d instanceof Array) {
                    err.empty();
                    d.forEach(function(o) {
                        err.append('<div>' + o.error + '</div>');
                    });
                    err.show();
                    return;
                };

                $('#f').trigger('reset');
                err.empty();
                err.show().html('SUCCESS! Please wait while the request is being made')

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here's what happens in the 'controller.js' end of things.

```
function json_form() {
var self = this;
var error = self.validate(self.post, ['intersection', 'hours', 'minutes', 'phone'])

if (error.hasError()) {
    self.json(error);
    return;
}

// save to database
var db = self.database('forms');
db.insert(self.post); 
self.json({ r: true });
```

}

```
function get_routes(hours, minutes, intersection) {
```

//The following code makes a call that returns an array with data to be rendered by another view controller. 
    var stops = this.module('cumtd').GetStopsBySearch('springfied busey');
}

Thanks for reading! Sorry for sounding confusing, I'm new to JS and Node programming. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in clide-side JavaScript, solution:

HTML:

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').bind('click', function() {
        $.post('/', $('#f').serialize(), function(d) {
            var err = $('#error');

            if (d instanceof Array) {
                err.empty();
                d.forEach(function(o) {
                    err.append('<div>' + o.error + '</div>');
                });
                err.show();
                return;
            };

            $('#f').trigger('reset');
            err.empty();
            err.show().html('SUCCESS! Please wait while the request is being made');

            // HERE REDIRECT:
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location.href = 'http://www.CaliCoder.com/results';
            }, 3000);
        });
    });
});
```